# ImportError: No module named darkflow.cli

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I just want to do live object recognition from web-came using YOLO and while testing it, I am facing some issues. I am using Ubuntu os. Here is the error I  get in terminal.

```
rajan@RGR:~/yolo setup/YOLO_Object_Detection-master$ ./flow --model cfg/yolo-new.cfg --load bin/yolo-new.weights --demo videofile.avi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./flow", line 4, in <module>
    from darkflow.cli import cliHandler
ImportError: No module named darkflow.cli
```

Here is the link of the git repository which I am using as refenrece:
https://github.com/llSourcell/YOLO_Object_Detection

Comment: have you included the path of dakflow.cli (library/package) to your ubuntu path using "export .." commands or included the path in your bash file ?

Comment: Thank you for your help Tahera Tabassum, i just changed " #! /usr/bin/env python " to "#! /usr/bin/env python3" in 'flow' file